# Putting two images next to each other that are 0.5\textwidth wide

Tags: graphics, positioning

I need to put 4 images in one group and put it on the page. All images have the same length and width, however I have problem with placing them by two in a row. I used this code

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{CircleTemplate.eps}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{CircleOlimpicStarting.eps}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth] {CircleOlimpicFinishing.eps}
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth] {CircleOlimpicFinishingWithNoise.eps}
\caption{Some long long caption  }
\label{fig:OlimpicCircleTT1}
\end{figure}
```

however it doesn't work - images were added one below the other. I also would like to put two (4 images) group in one page. Is it possible to adjust dimensions of these images somehow to fit all these images in one page

Please take a look at the pictures which show what I want to achieve

This is what I want to acomplish:

[image]

And this is what I get using the code presented at the beginning:

[image]

Comment: Do the images need their own subcaption?

Comment: No, all 4 images should have only one common caption

Comment: As new user without image posting privileges simply include the image as normal and remove the `!` in front of it to turn it into a link. A moderator or another user with edit privileges can then reinsert the `!` to turn it into an image again.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Box them together and look out for trailing spaces/line breaks:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\centerline{%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{CircleTemplate.eps}%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth]{CircleOlimpicStarting.eps}%
}%
\centerline{%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth] {CircleOlimpicFinishing.eps}%
\includegraphics[width=0.5\textwidth] {CircleOlimpicFinishingWithNoise.eps}%
}%
\caption{Some long long caption}
\label{fig:OlimpicCircleTT1}
\end{figure}
```

Another alternative would be to use a `tabular` with `{@{}c@{}c@{}}` as column specification to avoid any inter-column spaces.

Note: The line endings in the source code will be taken as space if you don't use `%` to comment them out. So basically you ask for `<image with 50% textwidth><space><image with 50% textwidth>` which is slightly wider than the text width and therefore will be broken into two lines.

---

If you want some space between the images you can use the following:

```
\begin{figure}[h]
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{image1}%
\hfill    
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{image2}%
}\\[0.5cm]% If you want some vertical space
\makebox[\textwidth]{%
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{image3}%
\hfill    
\includegraphics[width=0.49\textwidth]{image4}%
}%
\caption{Some long long caption}
\label{fig:OlimpicCircleTT1}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Result]

Comment: I used Your code and it seems that all images are now in one row. Should I use some line break to put last two images in second row ?

Comment: See the update code (or remove the `%` after the first `\mbox{ .. }`)