# Layout of n x m figure which use the maximal available space

Tags: floats

Is there any elegant way to layout multiple images like this automatically:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{eval1.pdf}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{eval2.pdf}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{eval3.pdf}
    \\
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{eval4.pdf}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{eval5.pdf}%
    \includegraphics[width=0.32\textwidth]{eval6.pdf}
    \caption{Results for four scenarios}
    \label{results}
\end{figure}
```

This methods becomes somewhat tedious when using different layouts like 5x2 or 6x2. I would like to say "use x% of the maximal available width for theses n images and put a white space of d between them".

**Edit:** This question previously also included a problem with the missing % which screwed up a 2x2 layout when using `0.5\textwidth` instead of `0.49\textwidth`. Thanks to Torbjørn for pointing this out!

Comment: The line break between the `\includegraphics` creates a space, add a `%` at the end of the line.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Now it's my turn... Can you turn it to an answer?

Comment: @karlkoeller Not sure, then it could perhaps be closed as a duplicate of http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19922/where-are-the-necessary-places-to-be-appended-with-to-remove-unwanted-spaces Also, it doesn't really answer the more general question.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Probably this one http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/23835/27635

Comment: So theses are basically two questions and I would be interested in the more general. So I edit the question accordingly.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125675/automatic-scaling-of-tikz-images-in-floatrow/125722#125722 may be relevant, too.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering

    \setkeys{Gin}{width=0.32\textwidth}
    \includegraphics{eval1.pdf}\hfill
    \includegraphics{eval2.pdf}\hfill
    \includegraphics{eval3.pdf}\hfill
    \includegraphics{eval4.pdf}\hfill
    \includegraphics{eval5.pdf}\hfill
    \includegraphics{eval6.pdf}

    \caption{Results for four scenarios}
    \label{results}
\end{figure}
```

Then you just need to set the width of each figure once, there is no need for manually adding `\\` TeX will use its normal paragraph breaking algorithm to distribute the images to lines as needed.

Comment: six scenarios ... :)