# Adding captions to sub-figures

Tags: captions, subcaption

For the question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23835/putting-two-images-next-to-each-other-that-are-0-5-textwidth-wide), how can we add captions to each sub-figure?

Comment: See this answer: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148445/18228

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Usually, we don't put a greeting or a “thank you” in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. [Accepting and upvoting answers is the preferred way here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about) to say “thank you” to users who helped you.

Comment: Since the linked duplicate question deals with the same and the answer provides several ways of doing it, we can close this question as a duplicate since there's not much additional value in also answering here.