# How can I place dot2tex graphs next to each other?

Tags: tabularx, tabu, dot2tex

I have two dot2tex graphs that have a relatively large height and small width. The combined width of the graphs is considerably smaller than the text width.

For example:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{scrbook}

\usepackage{dot2texi}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{dot2tex}[dot,options=-tmath --autosize --cache]
    digraph {
    u[label="u"];
    }
  \end{dot2tex}
  \begin{dot2tex}[dot,options=-tmath --autosize --cache]
    digraph {
    v[label="v"];
    }
  \end{dot2tex}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Compile with

```
pdflatex --shell-escape test.tex
```

These graphs should be placed next to each other like if they were in a table spanning the entire text width and each of them centered in its own column.

Unfortunately, none of the approaches mentioned in [Putting two images next to each other that are 0.5\textwidth wide](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/23835/putting-two-images-next-to-each-other-that-are-0-5-textwidth-wide) has worked for me so far, both fail with error "! Argument of \verbatim@ has an extra }." at the end of the `centerline` or `makebox` directives.

I tried aligning the graphs using a table as described in [How to force a table into page width?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/10535/how-to-force-a-table-into-page-width) but could not get any of the approaches to work. I could not find the right options for `tabularx` to get my desired result, both `tabu` and `tabularx` fail with "! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \verbatim@."

Is it expected that these packages don't play nice with dot2tex? And is there any other way to achieve what I am trying to do?

---

To clarify what the problem is:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{XX}
  \begin{dot2tex}[dot,options=-tmath --autosize --cache]
    digraph {
    u[label="u"];
    }
  \end{dot2tex}
  &
  \begin{dot2tex}[dot,options=-tmath --autosize --cache]
    digraph {
    v[label="v"];
    }
  \end{dot2tex}
  \end{tabularx}
\end{figure}
```

This should give me the layout I want. However, upon compiling this yields the following error message:

```
! Forbidden control sequence found while scanning use of \verbatim@.
```

Comment: Please, show us a MWE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is totally unclear but guessing from the error message I'm assuming that the markup you show is replaced by a `verbatim` environment by some pre-processor before being seen by LaTeX. To get two verbatim environments side by side you want two `minipage` so I assume you can do

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
  \begin{dot2tex}[dot,options=-tmath --autosize --cache]
    digraph {
    u[label="u"];
    }
  \end{dot2tex}
  \end{minipage} %space
  \begin{minipage}{.4\textwidth}
  \begin{dot2tex}[dot,options=-tmath --autosize --cache]
    digraph {
    v[label="v"];
    }
  \end{dot2tex}
   \end{minipage}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I make my question more clear? I tried to use your solution in a `tabularx` environment but unfortunately the error message is the same as before.

Comment: @Chris You can't use verbatim in the argument to another command (which as documented also applies to tabularx) Why would you want to put it in tabularx? It presumably has a fixed width layout so tabularx X columns are not appropriate

Comment: @Chris To make your question more clear: _all_ questions should have a _complete_ document so people can reproduce the problem. If using a non standard processor as here you might also say something about _how_ to run the example.

Comment: Sorry, I will amend my question in that way. I am not really familiar with the inner workings of tabularx and dot2tex so I did not realize that those do not go together. Do you have any other suggestion to achieve the layout I described?

Comment: @Chris the answer above should make the layout you ask for tabularx is totally inappropriate there (even if it worked)

Comment: Using your code without tabularx gives me "! Paragraph ended before \begin was complete." in the line directly after `\end{figure}`.

Comment: @Chris yes does when I try it but I haven't got the software so I get `Package dot2texi Warning: Conversion of zz387-dot2tex-fig1.dot failed..` so can't really test.  Oh flip there is a missing brace `\begin{minipage{.4` should be `\begin{minipage}{.4`  will fix now...

Comment: Thank you very much for your patience with me! Now the graphs are at least next to each other, just not aligned correctly (right one is too far to the left).

Comment: @Chris you can change the relative widths of the two minipages,

Comment: Thanks, I fixed it using `\centering` inside the minipage. Thanks for your help!